# How to create simple "CHAT APP" using Flask-SocketIO, Python, Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io

How can I edit these codes so that when I click the button, the input texts will be appended to the empty unordered lists and be able to broadcast to other "users"?

## HTML code

```
    <body>
       <ul>
       </ul>
       <input type="text" id="myMessage">
       <button>Send</button>
    </body>
```

## Javascript Template code

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + '//' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);

    socket.on('connect', () => {

    });

    socket.on('announce chat', data => {

    });
});
```

## Python code

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = os.getenv("SECRET_KEY")
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

@socketio.on("submit chat")
def chat(data):
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you dont call your submit chat and you should format it like submit_chat not with white space in between.

On your socket.io script you dont have submit_chat called you do have announce chat...

```
 socket.on('submit_chat', data => {

});
```